# Any issues calling back end service from fault seqeunce

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We have a requirement to call one of the back end service with call mediator from default fault sequence in case of times outs in normal end points. Do we always need to exit from the fault sequence in case of any time outs OR we can have a logic to call back end services from fault sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your use case is related to guaranteed delivery. I suggest you to use Message store and message processor combination to achieve this. There you can specify retry attempts. You simply need to use store mediator to store the message into a JMS store to which Scheduled Message Forwarding Processor is listening. The message processor will then send the message to the endpoint and send the response back. Also the message processor will ensure the guaranteed delivery too. You may find more information here. If you need to have a deep dive in to the message processor please refer my blog post at [2].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Sample+702%3A+Introduction+to+Message+Forwarding+Processor

[2] http://ravindraranwala.blogspot.com/2015/09/message-processor-coordination-support.html